# Get active tab on different component - Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got a page which I can display on 2 different tabs.

I'd like to know which tab is the active one when I enter on this page using `ionViewWillEnter`.

I can change active tab using `this.navCtrl.parent.select(2);` but couldn't find the way to get the active.

Answer (score 0):

You can only check for active tab with `ionViewDidEnter`. `ionViewWillEnter` is when the page is about to become active.

Comment: Oh I see... that's why it wasn't working all the time. The point is that I need to do something before it loads. I'm also asking not for that page, I'm asking about its parent. The tab was active before this page. I can do it with jQuery but I'd like to use `Ionic`

Comment: I tried with jQuery and ionViewDidEnter but none of them seem to work